# Material grid filling entire screen with scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a started angular material project. In `app.component`, I have a toolbar and a router outlet. In home component I have a grid list with two columns. These two columns filling the entire space with scrolling. I don't want the scrolling. How Can I fill the available space without scrolling.

**Code:**

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Va Ranjith Dashboard</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="home-container">
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="fit">
    <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

**screenshot:**

[image]

I haven't added any styling in that grid list but i'm getting the scroll bar. How to get rid of it. I can use `overflow` as hidden but If I have content it'll definitely go beyond that. Please advice.

Comment: rowHeight="fit", what happens if you remove this?

Comment: remains the same. nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumble upon similar issue.
In my case it was necessary to use below css style:

```
mat-grid-list, mat-grid-tile {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```